# How do I change /home mount point to 2nd encrypted drive where previous /home directy is after new Ununtu install on first SSD

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption

I had to do a complete new install on my first drive, which is an SSD. My previous installation had my /home directory on the 2nd drive, an HDD. Both drives were encrypted. How would I change my /home directory to the previous one where my 18 years of data is located taking into consideration it is encrypted. Also, how do I make it de-crypt on boot along with the first drive where /root is?

I have done re-installs previously and merely chosen not to format the drive when setting it up for the /home directory during the installation. The problem now is the drive is encrypted. I am not sure how to handle that since formatting is not an option when selecting the drive using the manual setup during installation.

The drive is visible before I unlock it, but when I click on it and type in the password for unlocking it, it is no longer visible. I am sure that is because it is setup to mount as /home and that is already done on the SSD under the master partition /root in the new installation.

Current install is Ubuntu 22.04. The type of encryption for my new installation is sfr, I think. Not sure. I know it is not LVM. There were two choices when selecting to encrypt the drive. The first was LVM and the second was sfr and erase drive.

This my new fstab file.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=09FE-5FE2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
/boot/efi/grub  /boot/grub      none    defaults,bind   0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptoswap  none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

The below is the result of lsblk

NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                                           7:0    0  61.9M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1405
loop1                                           7:1    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop2                                           7:2    0 155.6M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/1232
loop3                                           7:3    0 248.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop4                                           7:4    0  81.3M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop5                                           7:5    0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/575
loop6                                           7:6    0  43.6M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/15177
loop7                                           7:7    0   284K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
sda                                             8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1                                          8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                                          8:2    0   513M  0 part  /boot/grub
│                                                                        /boot/efi
├─sda3                                          8:3    0     2G  0 part
│ └─cryptoswap                                253:1    0     2G  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─sda4                                          8:4    0     2G  0 part
└─sda5                                          8:5    0 442.6G  0 part
sdb                                             8:16   0 698.6G  0 disk
└─sdb1                                          8:17   0 698.6G  0 part
└─luks-9beeb354-1481-410f-9ab9-8793fc6aa737 253:2    0 698.6G  0 crypt
sdc                                             8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1                                          8:33   0 931.5G  0 part
sdd                                             8:48   1     0B  0 disk
zd0                                           230:0    0   500M  0 disk
└─keystore-rpool                              253:0    0   484M  0 crypt /run/keystore/rpool

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details, also not told us what type of encryption (Ubuntu hasn't always had the same encryption defaults so its helpful to be specific). You just the system what you want mounted (and where) via the *file-system table* (`/etc/fstab`) though if you have a `/home/` directory on your current `/` system drive, that will be *shadowed* when you mount another. (*your details I didn't understand sorry as I'd have preferred to see your current setup, ie. current fstab*)

Comment: Current install is Ubuntu 22.04. The type of encryption for my new installation is sfr, I think. Not sure. I know it is not LVM. There were two choices when selecting to encrypt the drive. The first was LVM and the second was sfr and erase drive. I added my fstab file in my original post.